# jar file in Build Path not deploy into WEB-INF/lib folder

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7, myeclipse

I am getting error below when I deploy my project in tomcat:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
```

It was due to missing of `apache-log4j-extras-1.0.jar` library. So I add the required jar files into my build path like the screenshot below:
[image]

I refresh and clean the project, and try to deploy again, but still didn't see the log4j and guava in my `WEB-INF/lib` folder under tomcat webapps. If I copy and paste the jars into `WEB-INF/lib` folder it will works, no error. But I don't want to copy paste each time I re-deploy the project. Please help.

Comment: I'm assuming this is not a Maven project? How are the other libraries added to the project? You should not need to modify the Libraries tab, that would be automatically managed to if you put the files in the right place.There's more information here: https://www.genuitec.com/docs/servers/deployment-assembly/